# How to create a modal confirmation dialog before delete with ember-cli

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to create a users manager, I can create edit and delete users, In the delete action I want to display a modal confirmation dialog with a "proceed" & "cancel" buttons, to confirm user's suppression.

What are the best practice to do that, I am using ember-cli 0.2.3, There a lot of suggestions in the net, I am a little bit confused with those solutions, what is the standard or the best way to create modals with Ember-CLI ?

Comment: You can use the plugins available **[here](http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/confirm-box)**

Answer (score 2):

YOu should bind your toggleModal function with the delete button and your deleteUser fucntion with the 'ok' button in the modal.

For example:

```
//button to call modal
<button {{action 'showModal' 'modal-main'}}>Delete User</button>


//ok button on the modal
<button {{action 'deleteAfterConfirm' 'modal-main'}}>Ok</button>

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        deleteAfterConfirm: function(userId) {
          if (confirm("Want to delete?");) {
             //deleteUser
          }
        },
        showModal: function(targetId) {
            var modal = Ember.Views.views[targetId];
            modal.send('toggleModal');
        }
    }
});
```

You can see [here](http://blog.atmartin.io/a-dead-simple-ember-cli-modal/) in detail how to create and style your modal

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, "modal-main" it's a component ?

Comment: main-modal is the id of your component.

Comment: For example: $ ember generate component modal; {{#modal enabled=false id="modal-main"}}
     loading....
{{/modal}}

Comment: component should have `-` in them so `$ ember generate component modal-alert` should be the right way

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bootstrap's modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) and bind an action to the 'proceed' button.

Live demo of Bootstrap's modal [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo).